# How do I get the text from whatever code editor the user is currently using? - Autoit

Tags: regex, autoit

I want to create hotkeys that can automatically generate code for me. This is my start on it.

```
Func test1()
    Global $endString
    Global $nOutput
    Send("^a^c")
    $clipboard = ClipGet ()
    $endString = "Hello World"
    $nOutput = StringRegExpReplace($clipboard, "}[\n]*\z$", $endString)
    ClipPut($nOutput);
    Send("^v")
EndFunc   ;==>test
```

To modify the script I am sending the hot keys to copy all, editing it and then pasting over all. Its a bit odd but it worked until I tried the regex you see above to find the last } in the document. I suspect the clipboard doesnt have it \z. Any idea how I can do this and properly copy the file that is currently being worked on? If not... different regex?

Thanks all

Comment: Try `"}\s*$"` or `"}\s*\z"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HotKeySet('^r', '_test1')
HotKeySet('^q', '_Quit')

While 1
    Sleep(10)
WEnd

Func _test1()
    Local Static $endString = "; Hello World"
    Local $sOutput

    ; End the tool tip.
    ToolTip("")

    ; Get the window handle and keep it active on send.
    $hWin = WinGetHandle("")
    SendKeepActive($hWin)

    ; Select all and copy to clipboard.
    Send("^a^c")
    Sleep(200)

    ; Get text from clipboard and check if empty.
    $clipboard = ClipGet()
    If $clipboard == "" Then
        ToolTip("Clipboard is empty.")
        AdlibRegister('_TimeOut', 1000)
        Return
    EndIf

    ; Replace }$ with }$endString$.
    $sOutput = StringRegExpReplace($clipboard, "(*ANYCRLF)(?m)\}$", "}" & $endString)

    ; Put text to the clipboard and then paste the text.
    If @extended Then
        ClipPut($sOutput)
        Send("^v")
    Else
        ToolTip("No replacements to paste.")
        AdlibRegister('_TimeOut', 1000)
        ClipPut("")
    EndIf

    ; Deactivate send keep active window handle.
    SendKeepActive("")
EndFunc

Func _TimeOut()
    ; End the tool tip.
    ToolTip("")
    AdlibUnRegister('_TimeOut')
EndFunc

Func _Quit()
    Exit
EndFunc
```

The example does a little more checking so that you may see
if it is working ok or not.

If you use `Send()` then consider `SendKeepActive()` to ensure the
window is activated before use of `Send()`.

No reason the variables needed to be `Global` so I set them as `Local`.
The `Static` just assigns the variable value once so it just saves
reassigning each time the function is called.

The character `}` in regular expression (PCRE) is for
character or group repetitions i.e. `a{4}` is a pattern
to find `aaaa`. To use `}` literary, you need to escape
it with a backslash i.e. `\}`.

The PCRE pattern allows for any CRLF sequence. Use
multiline handling `(?m)` so the subject is treated
line by line and allows the use of the end of line
anchor `$`.

Note a `Sleep()` after `Send("^a^c")` as it improves the
chances of success for the select all and copy. I was
viewing up to 50% failure for the copy as the script
progresses too quick for the system. Many clipboard managers
use a sleep as well.

I used `ToolTip()` to inform of issues and used `AdlibRegister()`
to cancel the tips else they remain.

Use Hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to replace
and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to write this out for me. As a beginner Autoit is taking some learning.

I used what you gave me here and wrote a function that allows me to run a bunch of regex replacements at once. The code is here https://pastebin.com/kbG3mBXY

You seem to know what you're talking about so if you have some time and don't mind reviewing it I would love any feedback. Thanks again you rock!

Comment: My role is to answer the question posted. Not reviewing code off-site. That said, your off-site code has a `While` loop with no `Sleep(10)` which can stress the CPU for nothing. Minor issues exist such as missing `_TimeOut()` function and using `Call()` when a direct function call is adequate. If my answer is acceptable, then consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: Didn't mean to impose. Just thought you might be curious or just out looking to help. Thanks for the tips I'll be sure to address them.

Comment: The progress with the improvements is *very good* for a beginner so *thanks* for the link. My previous comment was never intended to offend you nor oppose discussion about the Q&A :).